# Passing and storing lambda function as callbacks

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, lambda

I was wondering if this would be an accepted approach to writing callbacks:

Storing callbacks:

```
struct EventHolder {
    std::function<void()> Callback;
    EventTypes::EventType Type;
};
std::vector<Events::EventHolder> EventCallbacks;
```

Method definition:

```
void On(EventType OnEventType,std::function<void()>&& Callback)
{
    Events::EventHolder NewEvent;
    NewEvent.Callback=std::move(Callback);
    NewEvent.Type=OnEventType;
    EventCallbacks.push_back(std::move(NewEvent));
}
```

Binding event:

```
Button->On(EventType::Click,[]{
    // ... callback body
});
```

My biggest question would be regarding passing the Callback by value. Is this a valid approach?

Comment: You have some syntax errors here. EventHolder looks like a struct but is declared as an enum. Did you mean for EventType to be an enum?

Comment: Agentlien, yes it's a struct and was a small typo. Thanks.

Comment: Thought so. :) A tip for the future: Try to finish your code and try compiling it before finishing the post. That way, you have higher chances of getting quick high-quality responses while the question is still new. ;)

Comment: Your `On` function can be more general, taking a "universal reference" to anything from which an `std::function<void()>` can be constructed. See [this example implementation](http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/simple-observer-pattern-implementation-c11/) of something very similar, with [working code here](https://github.com/juanchopanza/cppblog/blob/master/Patterns/Observer/Subject.h).

Comment: Hello @juanchopanza, I actually have a templated version of this implementation and only simplified it for the example.

Comment: You can simplify the code in your `On`-function by using emplace_back, though.


`EventCallbacks.emplace_back({std::move(Callback), OnEventType});`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid approach to storing event handlers.

However, I would like to point out some details regarding the signature of your function for adding a callback. You worry about passing it by value vs by reference. In your example, you currently have:

```
void On(EventType OnEventType,std::function<void()>&& Callback)
```

This is good, as long as you will only ever bind this to rvalues. However, unless there are particular reasons why you want to disallow it, I would recommend that you always have a method which accepts parameters by value or lvalue reference and add the rvalue reference version as a complement, if deemed necessary.

Not having a method which takes an lvalue reference means your code will currently fail to compile given this:

```
std::function<void()> func([](){/*something clever*/});
// Do something necessary with func, perhaps logging or debug prints.
Button->On(EventType::Click, func);
```

For simplicity, whenever you're choosing how to pass a value, you can simply follow these guidelines in general:

- If you need a copy of or intend to modify the value sent in, without wanting to change the actual object passed: pass by value.
- If you intend to modify the value sent in, and want these changes to affect the actual object passed: pass by reference.
- If you do not want to change the object passed, but believe it is beneficial to avoid copying: pass by const reference.
- If you take parameters by value, reference or const reference, and believe there are valuable optimizations which can be achieved using the knowledge that the input parameter is a temporary: also allow to pass by rvalue reference.

Comment: Relevant article [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) from Dave Abrahams

Comment: @boycy I've updated my formulation slightly to make the case discussed in the article easier to identify.

Comment: Indeed @Agentlien, the article complements your answer and fills in more detail for other visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Functions are either raw function pointers or light weight classes that their copy constructor has no side effect, so their copy must act as original object, so this approach is completely ok. But why you pass object by value and then move it to your original container, you can pass reference and then copy it to your container and have an overloaded function that accept an r-value reference (should not be so important).

Comment: Hi BigBoss, I updated my example to include RValue references.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same Problem.
I wanted to know how Many Monitors exist and where they are.

At least I gave up and wrote a short structure.
Not nice, but I wanted just the Information.

Even Lambda I tryed, no chance in casue of definition of Lambda...
Not a fixed Addr and second couldn't construct as CALLBACK...

```
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct _sMonitors{
        struct DispInfo {
            HMONITOR    hMon;
    //      HDC         dcMon;      // Everytime NULL (What ever!)
            RECT        pRcMon;
        };
        list< DispInfo> List;
        _sMonitors() {
            EnumDisplayMonitors(0, 0, Func, (LPARAM)this);
        }
        BOOL static CALLBACK Func(HMONITOR hMon, HDC dcMon, LPRECT pRcMon, LPARAM lParam){
            auto& Struct = *((_sMonitors*)lParam);
            Struct.List.push_back({ hMon,*pRcMon });
            return 1; 
        }
};
_sMonitors Monitors;
```

As I would say in my Language!
Mann ging mir das auf den Sack...