# Using smart pointer instead of raw pointer for Observer design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, smart-pointers, observer-pattern

I have an implementation for Observer design pattern where `Observer` stores a list of `Subject` and vice versa. So in case a Observer/Subject goes out of scope, the corresponding object is deleted in the destructor and no dangling reference remains stored.

Thing is raw pointers are rarely used in modern C++ and I'd want to replace them with a smart pointer.

My understanding is the utility shouldn't be taking ownership of the objects so `std::weak_ptr` makes more sense to me. Does that sound fair?

If so, changing the underlying data structure to hold `weak_ptr` of `Subject` would make sense, yes?

```c
std::unordered_set<std::weak_ptr<Subject<T>>, std::hash<std::weak_ptr<Subject<T>>> _subjects;
```

I am unsure of whether there may be some corner cases where storing `weak_ptr` in an `std::unordered_set` could cause problems.

Running into compile errors related to the hash but below is the link to the sample code with weak_ptr.

[Code with weak_ptr (though it doesn't compile)](https://godbolt.org/z/x67Wb3nvG)

[Original sample code with raw pointer (shown below)](https://godbolt.org/z/cMTYoY3o7)

```
template<typename T>
class Subject;

template<typename T>
class Observer
{
    std::set<Subject<T>*> _subjects;        // TODO: change to smart pointer

    public:
    virtual void update(T val) = 0;

    void addSubject(Subject<T>* subject)
    {
        printf ("[Observer] Adding Subject to observer - ");
        _subjects.insert(subject);
        std::cout << "number of Subjects = " << _subjects.size() << "\n\n";
    }

    void removeSubject(Subject<T>* subject)
    {
        printf ("[Observer] Removing Subject from observer - ");
        _subjects.erase(subject);
        std::cout << "number of Subjects = " << _subjects.size() << "\n";
    }

    size_t getNumberOfSubjects()
    {
        return _subjects.size();
    }

    void doesExist(Subject<T>* sub)
    {
        auto it = _subjects.find(sub);
        std::cout << "[Observer] Subject Exists = " << (it != _subjects.end()) << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Observer()
    {
        while (!_subjects.empty())
        {
            (*_subjects.begin())->detach(this); 
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Subject
{
    std::set<Observer<T>*> _observers;  // TODO: change to smart pointer

    protected:
    Subject() = default;

    public:
    void attach(Observer<T>* observer)
    {
        printf ("~~ [Subject] Attaching observer ~~\n");
        _observers.insert(observer);
        observer->addSubject(this);
    }
    
    void detach(Observer<T>* observer)
    {
        printf ("[Subject] Detaching observer ~ ");
        std::cout << "observers size = " << _observers.size() << "\n";
        _observers.erase(observer);
        observer->removeSubject(this);
    }

    void notify(const T& val)
    {
        for (auto& observer : _observers)
        {
            observer->update(val);
        }
    }

    size_t getNumberOfObservers()
    {
        return _observers.size();
    }
    
    virtual ~Subject()
    {
        printf ("\n~Subject\n");
        printf ("Observer size = %ld\n", _observers.size());
        for (auto& obs : _observers)
        {
            obs->removeSubject(this); 
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ConcreteSubject : public Subject<T>
{
    T _value;

    public:
    void set(const T& value)
    {
        _value = value;
        this->notify(value);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ConcreteObserver : public Observer<T>
{
    public:
    void update(T value)
    {
        std::cout << "Observer Notified: " << value << "\n";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    ConcreteObserver<int> obs;
    ConcreteSubject<int> sub;

    sub.attach(&obs);
    sub.set(5);

    printf ("\n~~> Before detaching:\nnumber of subjects in Observer = %ld ~~\n", obs.getNumberOfSubjects());
    printf ("number of observers in Subject = %ld\n\n", sub.getNumberOfObservers());
    

    sub.detach(&obs);
    printf ("\n~~> After detaching:\nnumber of subjects in Observer = %ld ~~\n", obs.getNumberOfSubjects());
    printf ("number of observers in Subject = %ld\n", sub.getNumberOfObservers());
    
    // subject no longer exists in observer
    obs.doesExist(&sub);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can use templates, you don't have to use inheritance at all to create callbacks. Allow observers to register a lambda (store it in a std:function, or a vector of those). Then you don't even need to store the pointers to the observing objects. Just make sure your clients live long enough to receive the callbacks (or make a shared_ptr to them and capture that in the lambda you register). [Passing and storing lambda functions as callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652761/passing-and-storing-lambda-function-as-callbacks)

Comment: Also storing registrations in a set might be problematic. If client code registers same observer twice it will only be stored once. Then what should happen with two remove calls? So only allow registration to happen once, or store them in a vector

Comment: *"Thing is raw pointers are rarely used in modern C++"* - **Owning** raw pointers...

Comment: @PepijnKramer to your second point, wouldn't the second deregister call not go through any way since there ever was a single instance of the `observer`? to your first point, could my original code be modified to address the change you're referring to?

Comment: A little off-topic, but I've never seen the Subject/Observer pattern implemented such that the `Observer` _also_ holds onto the list of `Subject`s. I understand this is to attempt to unregister before destruction; but this doesn't stop race-conditions from occurring if notifications are multithreaded, since a context-switch could happen between starting the event notification, destructing, and finishing execution of the event notification (thus operating on a dangling object).

Comment: @Human-Compiler I don't know about OP. But it doesn't have to be multithreading problem. I had similar problem with native objects owned by Java objects. Since Java uses GC, deleting order of Java objects is undeterministic, though still happened in one thread.